# ValidationError: Expected the value to not be an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js

I'm trying to list the boat names and it's price so the user can pick and choose which boat they want to buy, not quite sure why it doesn't seem to work, I've tried several different ways to fix it but it still outputs the same exact error.

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { getUserById, updateUserById } = require('../utils/user');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('buyship')
        .setDescription('Buy a ship from the shop')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('ship')
                .setDescription('Select the ship you want to buy')
                .setRequired(true)
                .addChoices([{ name: 'Sloop', value: 'sloop' }, { name: 'Frigate', value: 'frigate' }, { name: 'Galleon', value: 'galleon' }, { name: "Man o' war", value: 'manowar'}])),
   
    async execute(interaction) {
        const ship = interaction.options.getString('ship');
        const shipPrices = {
            sloop: 100,
            frigate: 250,
            galleon: 500,
            manowar: 1000
        };
        const user = await getUserById(interaction.user.id);
        const balance = user.balance;
        const price = shipPrices[ship];
        if (!price) {
            return interaction.reply({ content: 'That is not a valid ship.', ephemeral: true });
        }
        if (balance < price) {
            return interaction.reply({ content: 'You do not have enough money to buy this ship.', ephemeral: true });
        }
        const newBalance = balance - price;
        await updateUserById(interaction.user.id, { balance: newBalance, ship: ship });
        return interaction.reply(`You bought a ${ship} for ${price} coins.`);
    },
};
```

```
ValidationError: Expected the value to not be an array
          at ObjectValidator.handle (/Users/humza/Desktop/Humza/pirate/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:1208:25)
          at ObjectValidator.run (/Users/humza/Desktop/Humza/pirate/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:193:23)
          at ArrayValidator.handle (/Users/humza/Desktop/Humza/pirate/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:462:37)
          at ArrayValidator.parse (/Users/humza/Desktop/Humza/pirate/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:207:88)
          at MixedClass.addChoices (/Users/humza/Desktop/Humza/pirate/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:1702:22)
          at /Users/humza/Desktop/Humza/pirate/commands/buyship.js:12:18
          at MixedClass._sharedAddOptionMethod (/Users/humza/Desktop/Humza/pirate/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:2008:50)
          at MixedClass.addStringOption (/Users/humza/Desktop/Humza/pirate/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:1987:17)
          at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/humza/Desktop/Humza/pirate/commands/buyship.js:8:10)
          at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14) {
        validator: 's.object(T)',
        given: [
          { name: 'Sloop', value: 'sloop' },
          { name: 'Frigate', value: 'frigate' },
          { name: 'Galleon', value: 'galleon' },
          { name: "Man o' war", value: 'manowar' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
 data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('buyship')
    .setDescription('Buy a ship from the shop')
    .addStringOption(option =>
        option.setName('ship')
            .setDescription('Select the ship you want to buy')
            .setRequired(true)
            .addChoices([{ name: 'Sloop', value: 'sloop' }, { name: 'Frigate', value: 'frigate' }, { name: 'Galleon', value: 'galleon' }, { name: "Man o' war", value: 'manowar'}])),
```

with

```
 data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('buyship')
    .setDescription('Buy a ship from the shop')
    .addStringOption(option =>
        option.setName('ship')
            .setDescription('Select the ship you want to buy')
            .setRequired(true)
            .addChoices(
                { name: 'Sloop', value: 'sloop' },
                { name: 'Frigate', value: 'frigate' },
                { name: 'Galleon', value: 'galleon' },
                { name: "Man o' war", value: 'manowar' }
            )),
```

I simply removed the surrounding `[]` on the parameters passed into `.addChoices()`

[Discord.js API documenation](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/advanced-creation.html#choices) contains the following snippet which shows the `.addChoices()` function being used this way:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('gif')
    .setDescription('Sends a random gif!')
    .addStringOption(option =>
        option.setName('category')
            .setDescription('The gif category')
            .setRequired(true)
            .addChoices(
                { name: 'Funny', value: 'gif_funny' },
                { name: 'Meme', value: 'gif_meme' },
                { name: 'Movie', value: 'gif_movie' },
            ));
```